# fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found when coding battleship game in C++, Visual Studio

Tags: c++

I am programming a Battleship game in C++ and I cant get the print board code to work. I receive the following error fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the code:

Main Code

```
// Project 1.cpp: Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "printboard.cpp"


int main()
{
    printboard();
    return 0;
}
```

Printboard Code

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include < iostream>
#include < iomanip>

using namespace std; 

void printboard()
{ 
    int NUM_COLS = 10, NUM_ROWS = 10; //added by me

    cout << right;
    cout << "\n  =====> Current Board Status <=====\n";
    int row, col;



    // Print out the column heading values for the board
    cout << setw(7) << "0";
    for (col = 1; col < NUM_COLS; col++)
        cout << setw(3) << col;
    cout << endl;               // terminate the column heading line

    cout << setw(7) << "-";
    for (col = 1; col < NUM_COLS; col++)
        cout << setw(3) << "---";
    cout << endl;

    int board[10][10]; //added by me

    // Print out each row of the board
    for (row = 0; row < NUM_ROWS; row++)
    {
        cout << setw(3) << row << ":";
        for (col = 0; col < NUM_COLS; col++)
        {
            // if the position to print out is a boat, print out
            // a . instead.  Otherwise, print out the contents
            // of the position
            if (board[row][col] >= '1' && board[row][col] <= '4')
                cout << setw(3) << '.'; // hide the boat numbers
            else
                cout << setw(3) << board[row][col];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: You include a code file. That is the problem.

Comment: By the way, your way of including the pre-compiled headers related header "stdafx.h" multiple times, including indirectly and not as first header, you set up yourself for more problems than those you have already noticed...

Answer (score 0):

In this line (within one of your code files) you include another of your code files.

```
#include "printboard.cpp"
```

This effectively gets the included code file compiled as part of the including code file.
When you compile the included code file itself, all of what is defined there gets compiled again.

Fix by making a separate header "printboard.h" with only declarations:

```
void printboard();
```

Then include that header into the including code file and into the included code file. Do not include the code file.